# Objective-C return from nested functions (GCD)

Tags: objective-c, c, function, return, grand-central-dispatch

How would I return from nested GCD dispatch calls?

Let's say I have a method that looks like this:

```
- (void)foo {

    dispatch_async(queue, ^{

        if (flag) { 
            // I want out of here
            return;
        }

        dispatch_sync(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{

            if (flag) { 
                // I want out of here
                return;
            }
        });
    });
}
```

When I am inside `dispatch_sync` function and calling `return;` I'm thinking that will only leave that current function so that I would need to call `return;` again from `dispatch_async`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, your thinking is correct. Each block is a separate function, so return will only return from the current block. If you want to early-exit the dispatch_async'd block if the dispatch_sync'd one does, you'll need another check and return after the dispatch_sync.